# Errors were encountered while processing: linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, mac

I install Ubuntu 14.04 on Macbook pro. But every time when I do like apt-get XXXX in terminal ,it will always show the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic:
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic (= 4.4.0-101.124~14.04.1); however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-signed-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic; however:
  Package linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-signed-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-signed-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-signed-image-generic-lts-xenial (= 4.4.0.101.84); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic-lts-xenial is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up apport (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.27) ...
apport start/running
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-101-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-signed-generic-lts-xenial
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you write `apt-get xxx` or `sudo apt-get`?  For package installation, sudo is required.

Comment: I did write sudo apt-get.

Answer (score -1):

Try

> sudo apt-get -f upgrade

That option tries to fix the dependencies problems.

If it does not succeed, I would recommend to install the more recent 16.04 LTS version, with 5 year support, un less you have vey good reasons to stick to 14.04.

Comment: Thank you, but it still happens. Because I am using ROS indigo, I have to use Ubuntu14.04